# CMake subdirectory structure just won't include

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following folder structure:

[image: structure]

**Arrayhelper CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library(arrayhelper src/arrayhelper.cpp src/arrayhelper.h)
target_include_directories(arrayhelper PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
target_link_libraries(arrayhelper PUBLIC network neuralmath)
```

**network CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library(
    network
    src/layer.cpp
    src/layer.h
    src/network.cpp
    src/network.h
)
target_include_directories(network PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
target_link_libraries(network PUBLIC arrayhelper neuralmath)
```

**neuralmath CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_library(
    neuralmath
    src/functions.cpp
    src/functions.h
    src/matrix.cpp
    src/matrix.h
    )
target_include_directories(neuralmath PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
target_link_libraries(neuralmath PUBLIC arrayhelper)
```

**main CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_subdirectory(arrayhelper)
add_subdirectory(neuralmath)
add_subdirectory(network)


add_executable(main main.cpp main.h)
set(INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dist/")

target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC neuralmath arrayhelper network)
```

I don't see any mistakes in my code and I double checked for errors. I followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYgESCQeGJY

Error: [image]

Comment: Does the code build?  There's a big difference between intellisense complaining and something actually being wrong.  If the code doesn't build, you should post the compiler error.

Comment: You include the header as `neuralmath/functions.h` but none of the directory contains that sub-path. (You have `neuralmath/src` as include directory, but this directory contains simple `functions.h`, without subdirectory.)

Comment: So I didn't get the tutorial correctly. What do I have to write in the include path instead? I thought it's always the name I wrote in the add_library() method @Tsyvarev

Comment: No it doesn't build, It basically gives the same error when building with make afterwards. @MilesBudnek

Comment: "What do I have to write in the include path instead? I thought it's always the name I wrote in the add_library() method" - In `add_library` call you use `src/functions.h`, but in the code you attempt to include file in **other way**, as `neuralmath/functions.h`. As you have `neuralmath/src` as include directory, you may include the header as `functions.h`. Again, when select file for `#include`, look into **actual** files hierarchy. Because this hierarchy doesn't have `neuralmath/functions.h`, you cannot include the header using this way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but you are introducing a [circular dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency).

In `arrayhelper`'s CMakeLists.txt you are linking against `network` and `neuralmath`.
In `network`'s and `neuralmath`'s CMakeLists.txt you are linking against `arrayhelper`.

I am surprised that CMake is even parsing that correctly.